# Add new values to jquery chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

In my application I have used Jquery Chosen plugin, which gives some beautifully looking multiple selects in our form. The select can have some options populated, and the user can select one or multiple of them.

### [image]

Recently, while using this plugin, I wanted to allow the user to add his own values to the list dynamically. Currently, in case the value is not there in the result, a ‘No result found’ message is shown.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us the code (html and jquery) that you use to create and initialize one of your fields?

Comment: Also, do you want the user's additions to then be available to all other users, or just available for that user to select again in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use version this

```
// Chosen, a Select Box Enhancer for jQuery and Protoype
// by Patrick Filler for Harvest, http://getharvest.com
// 
// Version 0.9.5
// Full source at https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen
// Copyright (c) 2011 Harvest http://getharvest.com

// MIT License, https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/LICENSE.md
// This file is generated by `cake build`, do not edit it by hand.
```

HTML

```
 <select data-allows-new-values="true" 
style="width: 100%;" class="chzn-select-desele selLoc " >
                        </select>
```

Comment: /*!
Chosen, a Select Box Enhancer for jQuery and Prototype
by Patrick Filler for Harvest, http://getharvest.com

Version 1.3.0
Full source at https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen
Copyright (c) 2011-2014 Harvest http://getharvest.com

MIT License, https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/LICENSE.md
This file is generated by `grunt build`, do not edit it by hand.
*/ I'm using above version can you help me for this